# How to combine two queries to get one result?

Tags: sql

I need two combine two queries to get one result only. Here's the first code.

```
SELECT FKLTI_KTRGN, COUNT(DISTINCT VIEW_PELAJAR_ENROLL.MB_NAMA) AS BIL_UG 
FROM VIEW_PELAJAR_ENROLL, KOD_BANGSA, KOD_NEGERI, JANTINA, KOD_AGAMA, KOD_CACAT, TARAF_KAHWIN
WHERE KOD_KTRGN_PROGRAM = 'SARJANA MUDA'
AND MS_SESI = '2015/2016'
AND MB_BANGSA = KOD_BANGSA
AND KOD_NEGERI = MB_ASAL
AND MB_JANTINA = JAN_KOD
AND KOD_AGAMA = MB_AGAMA
AND KOD_CACAT = MB_CACAT
AND KOD_TARAF = MB_TARAF_KAHWIN
AND MS_STATUS_SEMASA IN
(SELECT SP_KOD
FROM STATUS_PELAJAR
WHERE STATUS_ENROLL = 'Y'
AND SP_TAMAT IS NULL
AND SP_KOD = MS_STATUS_SEMASA)
GROUP BY FKLTI_KTRGN
```

And this is the second code.

```
SELECT FKLTI_KTRGN, COUNT(DISTINCT PELAJAR_BIODATA.MBUT_NAMA) AS BIL_PG
                FROM PELAJAR_BIODATA,KOD_NEGERI,FAKULTI,KOD_IJAZAH,PELAJAR_BUTIR_PENGAJIAN,STATUS_PENGAJIAN A,
                KOD_STATUS_PELAJAR_IPS, KOD_CACAT, KOD_BANGSA, E_KOD_PENGAJIAN, JANTINA, KOD_PROGRAM
                WHERE   A.STAT_STATUS IN (SELECT KOD_STATUS
                FROM KOD_STATUS_PELAJAR_IPS
                WHERE  STATUS_ENROLL='Y'
                AND KOD_STATUS=STAT_STATUS)
                AND A.STAT_NOMKPB=MBUT_NOMKPB
                AND PBP_PROGRAM IN ('5','6')
                AND MBUT_ASAL=KOD_NEGERI(+)
                AND SUBSTR(A.STAT_KOD_IJAZAH,1,1)=FKLTI_KOD
                AND PBP_PROGRAM=KOD_PROGRAM.KOD_PROGRAM
                AND A.STAT_KOD_IJAZAH=KOD_IJAZAH_UM
                AND A.STAT_NODAFTAR=PBP_NODAFTAR
                AND MBUT_CACAT=KOD_CACAT
                AND KOD_BANGSA=MBUT_BANGSA
                AND PBP_JENIS_PENGAJIAN=KOD_JNS_PENGAJIAN
                AND MBUT_JANTINA=JAN_KOD
                AND MBUT_WARGA IS NOT NULL
                AND MBUT_BANGSA IS NOT NULL
                AND MBUT_JANTINA IS NOT NULL
                AND MBUT_NEGERI IS NOT NULL
                AND PBP_PROGRAM IS NOT NULL
                AND A.STAT_STATUS=KOD_STATUS
                AND PBP_KOD_IJAZAH IS NOT NULL
                AND A.STAT_SESI||A.STAT_SEMESTER IN (SELECT MAX(B.STAT_SESI||B.STAT_SEMESTER) FROM STATUS_PENGAJIAN B
                WHERE B.STAT_NODAFTAR=A.STAT_NODAFTAR
                AND B.STAT_NOMKPB=A.STAT_NOMKPB
                AND A.STAT_SESI||A.STAT_SEMESTER=B.STAT_SESI||B.STAT_SEMESTER)
                AND A.STAT_SESI = '2015/2016'
                group by FKLTI_KTRGN
```

This is the expected result:

[image: expected result]

This is what i get:

[image: actual result]

I've tried to use UNION but it doesn't work. Anyone can help me? I really need your help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How exactly `union` doesn't work for you? Both queries returns two columns of same type - so union *should* work.

Comment: UNION should work, what error did you get? But what do you want, could you show sample output for each query, and expected result for those sample output?

Comment: Add example result for each query, and show us the combined result as well - all as well formatted text!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Inlined pictures

Answer (score 0):

In order to use union, you need to have the same number of fields and the same field name of both query.

as in both queries of yours, the second field has different name: BIL_PG, BIL_UG

Comment: Column names doesn't matter, only number/order and column types should match. Column names from first query are being used as column names for result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select * from 
    (SELECT FKLTI_KTRGN, COUNT(DISTINCT VIEW_PELAJAR_ENROLL.MB_NAMA) AS BIL_UG 
    FROM VIEW_PELAJAR_ENROLL, KOD_BANGSA, KOD_NEGERI, JANTINA, KOD_AGAMA, KOD_CACAT, TARAF_KAHWIN
    WHERE KOD_KTRGN_PROGRAM = 'SARJANA MUDA'
    AND MS_SESI = '2015/2016'
    AND MB_BANGSA = KOD_BANGSA
    AND KOD_NEGERI = MB_ASAL
    AND MB_JANTINA = JAN_KOD
    AND KOD_AGAMA = MB_AGAMA
    AND KOD_CACAT = MB_CACAT
    AND KOD_TARAF = MB_TARAF_KAHWIN
    AND MS_STATUS_SEMASA IN
    (SELECT SP_KOD
    FROM STATUS_PELAJAR
    WHERE STATUS_ENROLL = 'Y'
    AND SP_TAMAT IS NULL
    AND SP_KOD = MS_STATUS_SEMASA)
    GROUP BY FKLTI_KTRGN)

    union

    select * from (SELECT FKLTI_KTRGN, COUNT(DISTINCT PELAJAR_BIODATA.MBUT_NAMA) AS BIL_PG
                    FROM PELAJAR_BIODATA,KOD_NEGERI,FAKULTI,KOD_IJAZAH,PELAJAR_BUTIR_PENGAJIAN,STATUS_PENGAJIAN A,
                    KOD_STATUS_PELAJAR_IPS, KOD_CACAT, KOD_BANGSA, E_KOD_PENGAJIAN, JANTINA, KOD_PROGRAM
                    WHERE   A.STAT_STATUS IN (SELECT KOD_STATUS
                    FROM KOD_STATUS_PELAJAR_IPS
                    WHERE  STATUS_ENROLL='Y'
                    AND KOD_STATUS=STAT_STATUS)
                    AND A.STAT_NOMKPB=MBUT_NOMKPB
                    AND PBP_PROGRAM IN ('5','6')
                    AND MBUT_ASAL=KOD_NEGERI(+)
                    AND SUBSTR(A.STAT_KOD_IJAZAH,1,1)=FKLTI_KOD
                    AND PBP_PROGRAM=KOD_PROGRAM.KOD_PROGRAM
                    AND A.STAT_KOD_IJAZAH=KOD_IJAZAH_UM
                    AND A.STAT_NODAFTAR=PBP_NODAFTAR
                    AND MBUT_CACAT=KOD_CACAT
                    AND KOD_BANGSA=MBUT_BANGSA
                    AND PBP_JENIS_PENGAJIAN=KOD_JNS_PENGAJIAN
                    AND MBUT_JANTINA=JAN_KOD
                    AND MBUT_WARGA IS NOT NULL
                    AND MBUT_BANGSA IS NOT NULL
                    AND MBUT_JANTINA IS NOT NULL
                    AND MBUT_NEGERI IS NOT NULL
                    AND PBP_PROGRAM IS NOT NULL
                    AND A.STAT_STATUS=KOD_STATUS
                    AND PBP_KOD_IJAZAH IS NOT NULL
                    AND A.STAT_SESI||A.STAT_SEMESTER IN (SELECT MAX(B.STAT_SESI||B.STAT_SEMESTER) FROM STATUS_PENGAJIAN B
                    WHERE B.STAT_NODAFTAR=A.STAT_NODAFTAR
                    AND B.STAT_NOMKPB=A.STAT_NOMKPB
                    AND A.STAT_SESI||A.STAT_SEMESTER=B.STAT_SESI||B.STAT_SEMESTER)
                    AND A.STAT_SESI = '2015/2016'
                    group by FKLTI_KTRGN)
```

Comment: How moving queries to sub-queries supposed to help in this particular situation?

Comment: there can be problem with distinct and count

Comment: There can't be such a problem. `count(distinct ...)` doesn't affects combining queries with `union` in any kind.